# USB HDD ext4 changes to read-only - what is the problem? - works on other system

Tags: debian, mount, raspberry-pi

I have attached a Seagate external hard drive (FreeAgent 750GB) to Open Media Vault on raspberry pi. As soon as any write operation is attempted the drive is remounted read only. The machine is raspberryPi v.1 B+ (r0OMV 4.1.13+). I can however attach the same drive to my  (manjaro 4.3.6-1-MANJARO) laptop and write to it without any problems.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Given that this is a disk that works OK on other systems I would not want to simply buy a new disk, because it might have the same problems with raspberryPi and OMV. I can repeat the below steps I have done and I get exact same results again. Just to say - this disk functioned OK for a week or so days on the same raspberryPi machine and still can function well with my laptop. The disk is 7 years old. My troubleshooting steps so far have been:

**1) Unmount and do fsck:**

```
root@r0OMV:~#  e2fsck /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ForteBKP: recovering journal
ForteBKP contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
ForteBKP: 11/45793280 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 2924481/183143385 blocks
```

immediately after I can mount it:

```
mount -a
```

then mount shows:

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/49fb4a0f-c826-4a7c-877a-76c98dba5b2c type ext4 (rw,noexec,relatime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,_netdev)
```

if I try to mkdir I get error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/49fb4a0f-c826-4a7c-877a-76c98dba5b2c/touch': Read-only file system
```

and mount shows:

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/49fb4a0f-c826-4a7c-877a-76c98dba5b2c type ext4 (ro,noexec,relatime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,_netdev)
```

as this happens syslog output is:

```
Mar  5 12:08:48 r0OMV kernel: [49725.089841] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: user_xattr,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0,acl
Mar  5 12:08:50 r0OMV kernel: [49727.055478] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
Mar  5 12:08:55 r0OMV kernel: [49732.679403] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 730073112
Mar  5 12:08:55 r0OMV kernel: [49732.679520] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
Mar  5 12:08:56 r0OMV kernel: [49733.120506] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
Mar  5 12:08:56 r0OMV kernel: [49733.134090] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

**2) Other steps taken:**
I have looked into **hdparm** and smartctl

```
root@r0OMV:~# hdparm -I /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST3750640AS                             
    Serial Number:      5QD40Q51
    Firmware Revision:  3.AFM   
Standards:
    Supported: 7 6 5 4 
    Likely used: 7
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
... the rest of output seems normal and I cut it for the sake of brevity

root@r0OMV:~# hdparm -r0 /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)

root@r0OMV:~# hdparm -W /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
 write-caching =  0 (off)
```

but this has produced no results.

With **smartctl** after long test I find that the result is

```
smartctl -H /dev/sda 
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [armv6l-linux-4.1.13+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Please note the following marginal Attributes:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   051   034   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 49 (92 106 63 32)
```

The rest of the parameters are withing normal limits when I check with `-a` flag I see that the tests I have done recently seem OK.

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               80%     15285         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     15285         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               80%     15285         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15285         -
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%     15276         -
# 6  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     15157
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a USB adapter that is following a similar behavior.
As weird as it sounds mounting ext3 as ext2 (means not journaling) allows the disk to work. Perhaps thats an option.